# How to check if the command was executed in bash script and do not execute this command again?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I don't want to source my .sh script every time before I start packer build command ... because I always forget to do this. These tasks are repeatable and it makes sense to  create a shell script for that.

**Problem**: If the command

```sh
$source env.sh
```

was executed once, I don't want to execute this command again but continue with the others. Is there any solution for that ? My script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "Today is $(date)"
echo "--------------------"
sleep 1.5
echo "1. Pass env variables"
source env.sh
echo "2. Check the configuration of Packer template"
packer validate example.pkr.hcl
echo "3. Build the image"
#packer build example.pkr.hcl
```

Comment: Maybe you can try evaluating the stuff done (modified/created) by env.sh script, before invoking that again in your script...

Comment: This depends on what `env.sh` looks like. As the first thing in there, you could check for an indicator that it has already been run (like existence of a specific environment variable), and if so, return immediately.

Comment: You can populate a variable with a specific value in `env.sh` and check for the value before running `source`.

Comment: The scope of effect of the `source env.sh` command on the shell environment will be restricted to one execution of the script containing that command.  Are you sure, then, that you actually want to avoid running it every time the script is executed?  Or from another direction, what does `env.sh` do that must not be redone?

Comment: To clarify it, I would like to say, that `env.sh` script contains some parameters of AWS. If I understand this correctly, I should export || pass these variables inside the VM only once if nothing has changed. Am I right ?

Answer (score 1):

Set an variable inside your script, then test for the presence of that variable at the top of the script. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "${ALREADY_LOADED}" -ne "YES" ]; then

...
# Put commands here
...

ALREADY_LOADED=YES
fi
```

If you want this to persist to child processes, then use an environment variable instead of a local one, by `export`ing it. But be aware: Some things are not inherited by child processes. For example, if your script sets an array variable, the child will not be able to see the array. So you may want to leave some commands outside the `if...then...fi` clause.